# jsScroller put text over background-bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I 'm trying to set jscroller text above background, but the problem when you minimize the screen, the background becomes broken and non-homogeneous with the size of the mini screen, what is the solution?

Javascript for Jscroller:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jscroller2-1.61.js"></script>
```

Html Jscroller:

```
<div id="image">
  <div id="scroller_container2">
        <div class="jscroller2_right jscroller2_speed-30" style="font-size:60px; line-height:60px; white-space:nowrap; margin: 0;">
            <a class="scroll_text_sh" href="#" style="padding-right: 20px">dfhsdfklsdhfsdf </a>

            <a class="scroll_text_sh" href="#" style="padding-right: 20px"> dfsdfsdgsdgsdgsdg </a>

            <a class="scroll_text_sh" href="#" style="padding-right: 20px"> dfsdfsdgfsdgdsg</a>

            <a class="scroll_text_sh" href="#" style="padding-right: 20px">dfsdfsdgfsdgdsg</a>

            <a class="scroll_text_sh" href="#" style="padding-right: 20px"> dfsdfsdgfsdgdsg</a>

        </div>
        <div class="jscroller2_right_endless" style="font-size:60px; line-height:60px; white-space:nowrap; margin: 0;">
        <a class="scroll_text_sh" href="#" style="padding-right: 20px"> dfsdfsdgfsdgdsg</a> 

        <a class="scroll_text_sh" href="#" style="padding-right: 20px"> dfsdfsdgfsdgdsg</a>
        <!--<div style="display: inline-block; width: 50px;"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/images/sh-separator.png" /></div>-->
        </div>
</div>
```

Css for Jscroller:

```
#scroller_container1, #scroller_container2, #scroller_container3, #scroller_container4 {width: 60%;height: 60px;text-align:center;overflow: hidden;}

#dummy {;# }
#scroller_container1, #scroller_container2, #scroller_container3, #scroller_container4 {overflow: auto;}
#image{
background-image: url('../images/qq.png');
height:95px;}
```

Thumbnail score before the screen is:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/evn5cznjeaoss1l/befor.png

Thumbnail score after the screen is:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2ig1xrfuumlg01/after.png

thank you very much..